# Edit my script and add a jQuery cookie to show popup only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I currently have a working popup when a user enters my product page to give them some tips on how to navigate the page. I am trying to show a popup only once per user. I know that i can Set a jQuery cookie to help me do this.

This is what i currently have:

I have these links included in the header of my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.cookies.2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This is my body:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="overlay-back"></div>
    <div id="popup">
        <img src="Assets/images/Deep_Close.png" class="close-image" />
        <h1>Reminder</h1>
        <h3>Please Click On Any Image To View More Information</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
#popup{
position:absolute;
display:hidden;
top:160px;
width:350px;
height:auto;
background-color:white;
z-index:6;
padding:20px;
border:solid 5px #333333;
border-radius:5px;
}
#popup h1{
font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:16px;
color:#3F5C9A;
border-bottom:1px #3F5C9A solid;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
#popup h3{
font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
color:#666666;
margin:0;
padding:5px 0;
text-align:left;
}
#overlay-back{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: #000;
opacity: 0.6;
filter: alpha(opacity=60);
z-index: 5;
display: none
}
.close-image{
display: block;
float:right;
position:relative;
top:-15px;
right: -15px;
height: 20px;
}
```

What i need to do is edit this script to only show the popup once per user, here is the script.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#overlay-back').fadeIn(500,function(){
        $('#popup').show();
     });

     $(".close-image").on('click', function() {
        $('#popup').hide();
        $('#overlay-back').fadeOut(500);
     });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried anythign with actually [setting and looking up the cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)?

Answer (score 0):

You can you [jQuery Cookie](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/).

```
if( $.cookie("alreadyShownToUser") === undefined ){

    $('#overlay-back').fadeIn(500,function(){
        $('#popup').show();
    });

    $.cookie("alreadyShownToUser", true);
}
```